# Photoshop Grey Instead of Black

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

I'm new to Photoshop. I'm trying to figure out what's happening in my Photoshop canvas. The color seems to be grey instead of black. And, each layer has a blue border line each time I click on the layer.

How do I get rid of this? And what's happening?[image]

Comment: Are your layers shapes, paths or rasterized? Did you make sure that you have set your layers to normal blending mode and that opacity is at 100%?

Comment: The layers are rasterized. Opacity is 100%.